# Backup of database X on SQL Server 2008 on server A - restore to SQL Server 2012 database Y on server B

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, backup, restore

I want to copy a SQL Server 2008 database to SQL Server 2012 with a different database name.

- Took a backup of 'production' and copied it to the SQL Server 2012 machine.
- Created a new SQL Server 2012 database with a 'test' name.
- Tried to restore the `.bak` file but SQL Server says 'test' is busy

What is the correct way top do this?

Basically getting a snapshot of a production 2008 database into a test 2012 environment.

Thanks

Bob

Answer (score 5):

Don't create the database on server B before restoring. Just restore it. It doesn't have to exist first in order to do that. This should work whether the database already exists or not (so perhaps you should consider using a better name than 'test'), just open a new query window:

```
USE master;
GO
RESTORE DATABASE test
  FROM DISK = 'E:\backup path\backup.bak'
  WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY,
    MOVE 'data_file_name' TO 'D:\data file path\test.mdf',
    MOVE 'log_file_name'  TO 'L:\log file path\test.ldf';
```

But I have no idea where you are getting a message about "busy" - are you restoring using the UI? Stop doing that - the UI is notoriously bad for assisting with tasks like backup and restore. And make sure you don't have any query windows etc. with their context set to the *existing* `test` database. To kick people out so you can restore over it, you can use:

```
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE test SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

To get the file names to place in the `MOVE` arguments, run this:

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'E:\backup path\backup.bak';
```

Comment: Getting Error Msg 3234, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Logical file 'D:\Blah.mdf' is not part of database 'WgtnTest1'. Use RESTORE FILELISTONLY to list the logical file names.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: @Bob `data_file_name` in my code above is supposed to be replaced with the *logical* file name, not the *physical* file name. Show the results of `RESTORE FILELISTONLY`.

Comment: Hi Aaron, that appears to be working (Big database, it will be a while.) How they can take a working process in the 2008 UI  and reduce it to tedious scripting in 2012 is beyond me. I guess I should be grateful for anything at all. RE. Paths. All are good. I just shortened here for brevity. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To do that in SQL Server management Studio:

1. Connect to the SQL Server 2012 instance
2. Right-click the **Databases** node and select **Restore Database**

[image]

3.Select **Device** and navigate to the .bak file

SQL Server will in the **Database** field automatically insert the name of the original database, read from the restored backup

[image]

4.You have to manually type the new name here. There's a drop-down menu, but it shows only existing databases

[image]

5.Click **OK**